# How do I check the network speed right now?

Tags: ethernet

I know about `vnstat` and that tracks over the hour/day/months. I would like to see the network speed right now. As in for a duration of a second or at most a minute. Kind of like how top can show me the current CPU usage.

How might I check that? My port is not called `eth0`, it's `em2`, so I hope that doesn't conflict with anything.

Answer (score 1):

For terminal-mode I'd suggest using either [`netwatch`](http://www.slctech.org/~mackay/NETWATCH/netwatch.html) or [`jnettop`](http://jnettop.kubs.info/wiki/).

If you're looking for a graphical (X11) option, you could use [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/), [torsmo](http://torsmo.sourceforge.net/) (older than conky) or [gkrellm](http://members.dslextreme.com/users/billw/gkrellm/gkrellm.html).

If you want an extremely low-tech option, you could just use [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml):

```
# tcpdump -w - |pv >/dev/null
tcpdump: listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
2.77MB 0:00:44 [57.8kB/s] [                                                                              <=>           ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/) is worth a try.